# HPGENSELECT Restrict Statement

Tags: sas

I'm trying to understand how to use the `RESTRICT` statement in `PROC HPGENSELECT` fitting a multinomial logit model.

I have a categorical variable `evt_type` that takes 3 values (0,1,2).  I have 2 continuous regressor variables `x1` and `x2`.  I want to restrict the parameter on `x1` for `evt_type=2` to be 0.

Fitting without constraints:

```
proc hpgenselect data=to_reg;
   class evt_type;
   model evt_type(ref='0') = x1 x2 / link=glogit;
run;
```

Gives me:

```
                                     Parameter Estimates

                                                      Standard
   Parameter    evt_type    DF        Estimate           Error    Chi-Square    Pr > ChiSq

   Intercept    1            1       -0.092251        0.109479        0.7100        0.3994
   Intercept    2            1       -0.181718        0.119293        2.3204        0.1277
   x1           1            1        0.875623        0.097909       79.9807        <.0001
   x1           2            1       -0.017942        0.110512        0.0264        0.8710
   x2           1            1       -0.220358        0.113552        3.7659        0.0523
   x2           2            1        2.902520        0.199583      211.4960        <.0001
```

Trying to use restrict based on the documentation, it would seem to be:

```
proc hpgenselect data=to_reg;
   class evt_type;
   model evt_type(ref='0') = x1 x2 / link=glogit;
   restrict x1 0, x1 1  = 0;
run;
```

However that seems to restrict the parameter on `evt_type=1`.  What am I doing wrong:

```
                                         Parameter Estimates

                                                      Standard
   Parameter    evt_type    DF        Estimate           Error    Chi-Square    Pr > ChiSq

   Intercept    1            1        0.028338        0.100646        0.0793        0.7783
   Intercept    2            1       -0.202028        0.117543        2.9541        0.0857
   x1           1            0               0               .         .             .
   x1           2            1       -0.423127        0.099020       18.2597        <.0001
   x2           1            1       -0.159225        0.104655        2.3147        0.1282
   x2           2            1        2.914689        0.199375      213.7191        <.0001
```

Generate Sample data with:

```
%macro generate_sample(seed);
    proc iml;
    n=1000;
    call randseed(&seed);
    cov = {1 .0, .0 1};
    x = randnormal(n,{0,0},cov);

    c0 = {0, 0};
    c1 = {1, 0};
    c2 = {0, 3};

    vProb = exp(x*c0) || exp(x*c1) || exp(x*c2);

    vProb = vProb/ vProb[,+];

    NumTrials = 1;
    events = J(n,3,0);

    do i=1 to n;
        prob = vProb[i,];
        events[i,] = RandMultinomial(1,1,prob);
    end;

    out = events || x;

    create events from out[colname={'e0','e1','e2','x1', 'x2'}];
    append from out;
    close events;

    out = vProb || x;

    create true_prob from out[colname={"P_0","P_1","P_2",'x1', 'x2'}];
    append from out;
    close true_prob;
    quit;

    data to_reg;
    format evt_type $1.;
    set events;
    array e[3] e0-e2;

    do i=0 to 2;
        if e[i+1] then do;
            evt_type = put(i,1.);
            leave;
        end;
    end;
    drop i e0-e2;
    run;
%mend;
%generate_sample(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked with SAS Tech Support.  It seems the issue is with the `ref='0'` statement.  Changing the model ordering from `ref='0'` to `descending` seems to make things work.

This fails:

```
proc hpgenselect data=to_reg ;
   model evt_type(ref='0')= x1 x2 / link=glogit dist=multinomial;
   restrict x1 1 , x1 0 =0;
   restrict x2 0 , x2 1 =0;
run;
```

While this works:

```
proc hpgenselect data=to_reg ;
   model evt_type(descending)= x1 x2 / link=glogit dist=multinomial;
   restrict x1 1 , x1 0 =0;
   restrict x2 0 , x2 1 =0;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to the way SAS internally orders things when the `class` statement is used. If you set the class option `order = data`, it will appropriately apply the restriction.

```
proc hpgenselect data=to_reg;
   class evt_type / order=data;
   model evt_type(ref='0') = x1 x2 / link=glogit;
   restrict x1 0, x1 1 = 0;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think that works.  Try switching the 0/1 (`x1 1, x1 0 = 0`)and you will see that the other parameter will not be set to 0.

Comment: I tried sorting the dataset and it breaks the same way as well. Not sure what the issue could be...might be a bug? What happens with a 4-level?

Comment: Same behavior with a 4th level.  Might just submit this to TS.

Comment: It was with the ordering, but because of the `ref=` statement.  See my answer.